# Two calendar form in one page Joomla

Tags: joomla

I implemented two calendar form in one view page in joomla component.
the code is like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td>Start Date</td>
      <td><?php echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'from', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
    ?></td>

            </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>End Date</td>
    <td><?php echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'to', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
    ?></td>
        </tr>
```

But now only the first calendar form would pop up a jQuery calendar that let me select a date, the second form, when clicking on it, there is no effect.

Hope someone could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving same id for both calendar (Third parameter). it must be different ids for both calendar. try below code. [Reference code](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJHtml/calendar).

```
<tr>
  <td>Start Date</td>
  <td><?php echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'from', 'from_date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
?></td>

        </tr>
<tr>
  <td>End Date</td>
<td><?php echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'to', 'to_date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
?></td>
</tr>
```